# ROSbridge in Hydro

Tags: catkin, rosbridge, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have ROSbridge installed in fuerte. Now, since I have another package that needs to be run in Hydro,
I installed Hydro alongside with Fuerte.
The problem is, I used Labview-ROS toolkit by Clearpath and I know that it is not compatible with the
second version of ROSbridge in Hydro. So, how could I solve this with minimal effort. Redeveloping the program that
talks to the Rosbridge could take massive time, so I prefer to avoid this. =(
Would it be possible to rosbuild the ROSbridge version 1 in Hydro and keep on using Labview-ROS toolkit?

Worst case, I need to modify the client side to talk to the ROSbridge v2, but is it allow socket connection?

Thanks very much for any input.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193904/rosbridge-in-hydro/) by [clonzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/5689/clonzz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2014-09-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) on 2014-10-01**:
Too keep the threads clean this seemed to be a duplicate of http://answers.ros.org/question/193909/rosbridge-v2-accept-socket-connection/. In terms of TCP, yes, rosbridge v2 does have a TCP version.

**Comment by [clonzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/5689/clonzz/) on 2014-10-01**:
Sorry for the duplicate. I should have just editted the question. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosbridge v1 is deprecated and would not work on Hydro. Significant API changes occurred in Hydro preventing the Fuerte rosbridge v1 server to run in Hydro. The only viable solution is to re-implement the client-side program to use the new rosbridge v2 API calls.

---

Originally posted by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) with karma: 1173 on 2014-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [clonzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/5689/clonzz/) on 2014-10-01**:
I am still looking for the Rosbridge v2 documentation for socket connection. I may be able to build the client side. If you know where I can find it, please let me know. Thank you for the comment.